# How to search Japanese word using Apache Lucenes Indexer search?

Tags: apache, search, lucene

I am using Apache lucene's indexer search and to search a word I am using **MultiFieldQueryParser class**. It's working fine for English word but when I search for Japanese word its gives zero count for that word.

e.g.

```
MultiFieldQueryParser mqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]{"firstName"}, new StandardAnalyzer());
mqp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q =mqp.parse("*abc*");
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
 return hits;
```

abov code retun more than zero count for English word,

but when I search for Japanese word it s give zero count.

e.g.

```
MultiFieldQueryParser mqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]   {"firstName"}, new StandardAnalyzer());
mqp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q =mqp.parse("*あんくｒ*");
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
 return hits;
```

Comment: Hi, you have to use a Japanese Analyzer.

Comment: can you explain in detail? please..

Comment: @GweltazNiquel how to use Japanese Analyzer

Comment: What version of Lucene do you use ?
I can make an answer based on your version.
Otherwise : You have to replace "new StandardAnalyzer" by "new JapaneseAnalyzer" from package org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja

Comment: @GweltazNiquel  lucene 4.10.3

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use the appropriate Analyzer (It's the same for Chinese, Japonese and Korean) in org.apache.lucene.analysis.cjk :

```
MultiFieldQueryParser mqp = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[]   {"firstName"}, new CJKAnalyzer());
mqp.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query q =mqp.parse("*あんくｒ*");
TopDocs hits = searcher.search(q, 10);
 return hits;
```

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_3/analyzers-common/index.html

Comment: I used CJKAnalyzer , JapaneseAnalyzer but in both cases its giving zero result

Comment: You shall use CJKAnalyzer. JapaneseAnalyzer is a morphological analyzer.
You have nothing in your logs ?

Comment: Do you have some content in your index files ?
You can use Luke to see it's content (use version of Luke apropriate for your Lucene version) :
http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Comment: If we use StandardAnalyzer() then its working fine, but it is not seraching by word , its searching by character.                                                                                      e.g.  if we search for "abc" then it should return value which is having word "abc"    but its giving result which is having charaters "a" ,"b","c".

Comment: It's an IndexSearcher that you need to implement. Then.

Comment: Are you sure you missed nothing in that code example :
https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_3/core/index.html

Comment: @Gweltz Niquel Yes I tried but its not working for me.